# How do developers prevent a third party from looking at exposed information on a javascript console? For example on a public computer

Tags: web-browser, javascript

If a user was using your application on a public computer and were to log out of your website without closing the tab, the next person to use this computer could snoop through the console and look for errors logged there. Even if you weren't explicitly logging any request errors to the console you could forget to catch an error from an axios request. This then would be logged to the console. The third party could look at these errors and possibly find sensitive information or even the user's access token.

How would one prevent this? With `console.clear()`? Or would you reload the page on logout? Any other tips?

Comment: As a general rule, the onus is on the user to not walk away from a computer with any potentially-sensitive data exposed. There's only so much you can do to protect somebody who walks away with out closing their browser; that's going to leak a lot of history regardless. Of course, the onus is on the developer to not expose sensitive info into log files in the first place, whether or not the user knows the logs are there. If you're using libraries that aren't respecting that, you should file a bug with them, and treat them like any other vulnerable code (don't use it!) until patched.

Comment: @CBHacking Well sure, but it wouldn't it be easy to miss catching an error and then have that error logged onto the console along with any of its sensitive info? I can't really ask a library not to throw errors can I?

For example, axios will throw an error for certain status codes. It just feels to me that there should be a very easy way to prevent this from happening in production.